# Добавление динамических Views внутри ячейки

Tags: ios, swift

Как я могу сделать или какая библиотека мне поможет реализовать такое:

Это одни из ячеек в таблице, в которой я должен сделать возможность добавления сотрудников в таком виде

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Вариант первый - используйте UIStackView.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, данные приходят из сервера, и мне необходимо в эту ячейку заполнять эти labels, и контролировать количество таких элементов разделенные линией, я решил использовать view и section viewForHeaderInSection для этой ячейки, это вроде решило проблему